# Sorting multiple objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How do i sort my objects that contains numbers and other information?

I have 2 objects. The likes that is also link with the information object.
Likesobject contains random number while the viewname will be related to likesobject. Next thing is, viewname will be added more and more if there are new names coming in. So it wont just stop at d: link d

Example

```js
var viewnames = {
  'a': 'link a',
  'b': 'link b',
  'c': 'link c',
  'd': 'link d'
};

var Likeobject = {
  'a': 6,
  'b': 1,
  'c': 9,
  'd': 8
};
```

Example,

```
name1 -> 2 likes
name2 -> 5 likes
name3 -> 10 likes
name4 -> 8 likes
name5 -> 12 likes`
```

After sorting out from highest to lowest,

```
name5 -> 12 likes
name3 -> 10 likes
name4 -> 8 likes
name2 -> 5 likes
name1 -> 2 likes
```

```js
var obj1 = [{numLikes: likesobject},{viewerName: viewnames}];
```

I am not sure if the way I code my object is the right way. Do correct me if I'm wrong. Hope to get solution to my question.

Comment: do you have an example with real objects and your try?

Comment: You can always move your values to an Array, then sort it like that? A full example like Nina said would give us more information to help you with.

Comment: Hi @JimCiaston , i already updated the question.

Comment: just guessing, you have an array with names and one with likes and you want to sort both arrays with descending likes, right? if so please add an example of it.

Comment: Already updated! @NinaScholz

Answer (score 1):

Use the array.sort

```
var myArray = [
    {"numLikes": 2, "viewerName": "name1"},
    {"numLikes": 5, "viewerName": "name2"},
    {"numLikes": 10, "viewerName": "name3"},
    {"numLikes": 8, "viewerName": "name4"},
    {"numLikes": 12, "viewerName": "name5"}
];
printArray();
sortArray();
printArray();
myArray.push({"numLikes" : 17, "viewerName" : "name6"}); // add another object to the array
myArray.push({"numLikes" : 1, "viewerName" : "name7"}); // add another object to the array
printArray();
sortArray();
printArray();
changeNumLikes("name1", 7);
printArray();
sortArray();
printArray();

function sortArray() {
    myArray.sort(function(a, b){
        return a.numLikes-b.numLikes;
    });
}

function printArray() {
    for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        document.write("<span>" + myArray[i].viewerName + " : " + myArray[i].numLikes + "</span><br/>");
    }
    document.write("<br/>");
}

function changeNumLikes(viewerName, numLikes) {
    let object;
    for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i].viewerName === viewerName) {
            object = myArray[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (object && object.numLikes) {
        object.numLikes = numLikes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Understood your code. But viewername will be adding continuously. Exaample, maybe 2 or 3 more viewername will be in myArray. So it wont just be limited to 5.

Comment: The size of the array doesn't matter, as long as you sort it after each operation. I have updated the code. I also demonstrated how to change numLikes for a viewerName.

Answer (score 0):

> How do i sort my objects that contains numbers and other information?

You don't sort an object.

Why, because an object is an **unordered collection** of properties.

Comment: So how do i make them sortable?

Comment: The likesobject is basically the one containing all the likes information.

Comment: You can use an array instead and call the function `.sort()` on your array.

Comment: How sir? Any example. Sorry, i'm new to the sort array.

Comment: Pretty simple. Create an array and just type `YourArray.sort();`.

Comment: Hi Syafiq, you can try looking at this example and see if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value

Comment: I did before. But its not sorting. Keeps giving me [object Object]

Comment: please add your objects.

Comment: @Syafiq Question: Why do you want to sort your object? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to sort an array of objects by a objects property, so see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort you can give it a compare function.

Real object example would be useful.

Comment: The likesobject is the object that has the likes. like [1,2,4,5,7]

Answer (score 0):

You could get the keys in an array for sorting, sort by likes descending and use the keys array for generating a list of the sorted result.

This solution uses [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```js
var viewNames = { a: 'link a', b: 'link b', c: 'link c', d: 'link d' },
    likes = { a: 6, b: 1, c: 9, d: 8 },
    keys = Object
        .keys(likes)
        .sort((a, b) => likes[b] - likes[a]);
    
keys.forEach(key => console.log(key, viewNames[key], likes[key]));
```